# React native face detection library

Tags: react-native

Are there any face detection libraries out there? Specifically for a RN environment. Would be better if it's just pure javascript not depending on native modules.

Comment: I still did not find any packages that developed specifically for RN in field of face detection.. what I have done is using API from Microsoft Azure.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/face/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this, This turoial uses api and react native to accomplish : the results [Link](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-face-detection-app-with-react-native--cms-26491)